# Proper use of AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

The application I'm building is essentially an instrument with ten buttons, each linked to a separate `AVAudioPlayer`. When I try and allocate and initialize memory for each `AVAudioPlayer` in the ViewDidLoad method, I get no errors however the responsiveness of each button lags and there is considerable lag time before the same button can be triggered/heard again. I've rectified this situation by implementing the code below, however I'm not convinced it's the proper way of handling memory, especially because I have 10 of these methods.

```
    - (IBAction)note1:(id)sender {
           url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"note1" ofType:@"wav"]];
    unit1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url1 error:nil];
    [unit1 play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try,

Call `prepareToPlay` method of `AVAudioPlayer` before playing that file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current code is that you are creating new instance of `AVAudioPlayer` every time you call a `-note1:` You can try this improvement:

```
- (IBAction)note1:(id)sender {
    if (!url1)
       url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"note1" ofType:@"wav"]];

    if (!unit1)
       unit1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url1 error:nil];

    [unit1 play];
}
```

However best way is to initialise your `AVAudioPlayers` at one place, when your `UIViewController` is loaded:

```
- (void) initializePlayers {
    url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"note1" ofType:@"wav"]];
    unit1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url1 error:nil];
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [self initializePlayers];
}

- (IBAction)note1:(id)sender {
    [unit1 play];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help! Initialized in the ViewDidLoad and within the button method, made use of "unit1.currentTime = 0;"

Answer (score 0):

Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

```
NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Rondo_Alla_Turka_Short" withExtension:@"aiff"];
NSAssert(url, @"URL is valid."); 
NSError* error = nil;
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&amp;error];
if(!self.player)
{
    NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
}
```